# How do I specify a path in the worksheet.add command?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to programming in VBA. I want to insert a template into my worksheets. I Already have this code right now that works for the first step:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Then
    Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Target
 End If
End Sub
```

I know if you want to insert a template these are the steps: 
Expression: .Add(Before, After, Count, Type)

Type specifies the sheet type. Can be one of the following XlSheetType constants: xlWorksheet, xlChart, xlExcel4MacroSheet, or xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet. If you are inserting a sheet based on an existing template, specify the path to the template. The default value is xlWorksheet.

I really need to link type to my Projectonderdelen.xltm, located in C:\Users\stage\Documents\Aangepaste Office-sjablonen

Can anyone help me from this agony please?

Greetings, Brendon

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If 2 <= Target.Column And Target.Column <= 5 Then
        Dim ewbSource As Workbook: Set ewbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\stage\Documents\Aangepaste Office-sjablonen\Projectonderdelen.xltm", False, True)
        ewbSource.Worksheets("NameOfYourWorkSheet").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Name = Target.Value
        ewbSource.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that:

1) the condition in the If was wrong: you can't use Or this way, it would mean check if target Column is 2, which will be either True Or False, then evaluate True/False Or 3, which is 3, and if you convert non-zero values to boolean, they will be True, so this condition always evaluates to True.

2) To copy from a sheet from a template workbook, you need to open it. I also close it in the code assuming that it is not open initially.

3) Use fully qualified names: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets is not the same as ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm getting so many errors, I think first I'm going to need some training in this. Thanks for the effort guys, Brendon

Answer (score 0):

`If Target.Column = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Then` is not the correct syntx.

Either use:

```
If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 5 Then
```

Or, switch to `Select Case`,which allows you more versatility in the future to add more scenarios

```
Select Case Target.Column
    Case 2 To 5
        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Target.Value
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a bit, and do you know how to link the template while adding the new sheet?

Comment: Just put the link of the template into the `Type` parameter. `Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Type:="C:\Users\stage\Documents\Aangepaste Office-sjablonen\Projectonderdelen.xltm"`. All sheets from template will be copied.

Comment: @VincentG That was my first guess, but that didn't work. So I guess other parts of my code didn't fit this, or I've screwed up my template somehow. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, `Worksheets.Add ...` is not working on my test case, but `Sheets.Add ...` is. Try the later on.